# HR manager forgot to attach a job application. What should I do?

Tags: interviewing, email

My interviewer forgot to attach a job application I had to complete before the interview. He sent me an email, telling me that the interview would be on Monday, and that I had to fill in the attached job application. The thing is, nothing was attached. I sent him back an email asking kindly to check again but no answer since I sent the message at 7 PM. It's highly possible he wouldn't get back to me till next week because of the weekend.

What should I do now? It looks like I should fill out the job application before the hiring manager interviews me. Should I just wait and let them deal with it? Or what kind of email should I send to deal with this problem?

Comment: I would just wait. No point in spamming them. Just be ready on Monday morning to fill in the application in a hurry :)

Comment: @StephanBranczyk The answer may seem obvious to those who have previously been involved in a lot of interviewing from both sides. It may be less obvious to someone relatively new to the process who is anxious to do well. That makes it a good and answerable question, unless there is a duplicate.

Comment: interviewing is pretty stressful for inexperienced people, question looks reasonable to me as well

Comment: Sounds like a perfect opportunity to showcase your skills handling a situation when people fail to deliver.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk "The solution when solved will be simple." - Charles F. Kettering

Comment: As per my opinion no need to worry and by that time you can only do it be ready with all updated information from your side so when they ask on next business day you can fill it quickly.

Comment: Do yourself a BIG favor: get everything you might need ready now. In the US, this would be (but not limited to) SSN, current address, previous one if less than 2 years, previous employment for up to about 5 years, personal and professional/work references at least 2 each (name, address and phone number), an idea of your salary requirements, what insurance you have, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your mistake, and you have tried emailing with no response.

So don't worry about it, just fill in the job application on Monday while you are there. Take in your CV and any other paperwork you think you might need.

Firstly check your email for a reply early on Monday and keep checking up to the interview time just in case there are specific instructions on what to do, such as a reschedule or a reply with the form attached.

If not, then show up a little early and see if you can obtain an application form before the interview (some companies you can get one from reception). If you can't then just politely give your reason at the interview itself. The interviewer should have already read your email by now. If you don't have everything required by the application you have a perfect excuse, and if they like you at the interview, they'll give you leeway to get what you need.

Comment: The application might even be available on their website or job portal as well - if OP wanted to take the time to look.